# How to create a polygon with a specific length and to put a picture inside?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I would like to create a polygon with these sizes:
**Please note:** The sizes are only estimations and there can be errors for 1-2 mm. The most important size are the **2.5cm**.

[image]

The idea is to create a sticker and put a logo inside. Then the sticker should be filled as many times as possible on a DIN A4 page for cutting out.

That is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric, calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{hexagon/.style args={#1with image#2[#3]#4(#5)}{%
  regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,
  path picture={\node{\includegraphics[#3]{#5}};},
  inner sep=0pt,
  draw, thick, minimum size=#1, node contents=}
}%

\tikz{%
  \node at (0,0) [hexagon={2.5cm with image [scale=.5] (example-image-a)}, rotate=90];
}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

But I cannot figure out if the sizes are correct.

**Additionally** I would like to have this polygon filling a DIN A4 paper for cutting out.

Comment: Do you want or need it slightly asymmetric? And it's over-specified ...

Comment: Add `\draw[red] (0,-1.25) -- (0,1.25);` to draw a line with length 2.5cm and you will see that the hexagon has the correct size. According to the [manual](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#sec-71.3), `minimum size` is equal to the diameter of the circumcircle when used with the node shape `regular polygon`.

Comment: I was given the sizes above. They don’t match? Then I would like to have the various options to quickly change the "main" size (side, diameter etc.).

Comment: To see over-specification: 1) draw green and yellow perpendicular to each other. 2) put a tangent at yellow end point. 3) arc at green endpoint with radius 2.5 cm. Now all corners are determined from symmetry, and blue is a ... consequence, not a free parameter. // In reverse, IF it shall be a regular polygon, just one of the 4 lengths given is needed.

Comment: To draw a irregular hexagon with specific coordinates, better use a `\draw` command, not a node shape. You can "insert" the image using `clip` then. But I am unsure whether this is what you want actually.

Comment: I like to have a polygon with the sizes above and then put a logo in the center. not necessarily cropping the image . since this should be a sticker I need them filling a page for cutting

Comment: How is that possible to have middle size larger that the small size? I think if the small diameter is 4.35 and bigger one is 5, then the middle one should be between these two. isn't?

Comment: From geometry you simply can‘t have such an object, unless you allow a measurement error of about 1-2 mm …

Comment: I guess the most important size is the 2.5cm. errors like 1-2 mm are acceptable

Comment: If so: please rephrase and clarify your question. Thank you

Comment: Well, if the diameter of 5cm and the side length of 2.5cm are important: The hexagon you show actually *has* these dimensions. So, what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The measurements given does not make much sense - it can be many different hexagons e.g.

[image: Skewed hexagon with measurements]

-so I am going to assume that you just meant a regular hexagon with side length 2.5 cm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=0.2cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\tikzset{
hexagon/.pic={
\draw[clip] (30:1) -- (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
\node {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
\pic[scale=2.5, shift={({(\x+0.0)*sqrt(3)},0.0)}] {hexagon};
\pic[scale=2.5, shift={({(\x+0.5)*sqrt(3)},1.5)}] {hexagon};
\pic[scale=2.5, shift={({(\x+0.0)*sqrt(3)},3.0)}] {hexagon};
\pic[scale=2.5, shift={({(\x+0.5)*sqrt(3)},4.5)}] {hexagon};
\pic[scale=2.5, shift={({(\x+0.0)*sqrt(3)},6.0)}] {hexagon};
\pic[scale=2.5, shift={({(\x+0.5)*sqrt(3)},7.5)}] {hexagon};
\pic[scale=2.5, shift={({(\x+0.0)*sqrt(3)},9.0)}] {hexagon};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Page filled with hexagon pictures]

Comment: Hi. How do you done the First drawing? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I used Fusion360(free for hobbyists), but any CAD software could be used. https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/personal

Comment: Very good :-). I have upvoted you this morning.